# Windows 7 RunAs appwiz.cpl

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, uninstall

I am tasked with preparing our office with Windows 7. So right now I am in the test every application I can find that we run phase. I am doing this in our normal setup, which is a limited user. I do a runas on a cmd as my domain admin account (We are in an AD enviroment) and run the installer. That works fine. But when it comes time to uninstall the application and move on runas seems to fail me. I `runas /user:domain\adminuser cmd` then run `appwiz.pl` and it loads, but when I goto uninstall anything it errors saying I need to be an administrator. I attempted to do a `runas /user:domain\adminuser "control appwiz.cpl"` and same thing. It launched but error on an uninstall stating I need to be an admin. I also tried the local admin account in the runas as well. I ended up having to log out and login as the local admin.

I guess my question is, is there a more "proper" way of uninstalling applications on Windows 7 in an AD enviroment? 90% of the time we are remoting into peoples machines with them sitting there so I can't really log every user out when I have to reinstall something.

Comment: Does using "runas /user:domain\adminuser rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL appwiz.cpl" as the launch command work any better/differently?  Often I'll just use Runas to fire up a MSC, give the user temporary local admin access, do the work I need to do as them, then remove the access before disconnecting, so I've never personally run into what you're describing.

Comment: The runas you wrote out launches appwiz but still it has no admin powers. If I check its running under explorer.exe as the limited account.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have UAC on? If you do, it should prompt you for elevated credentials. You shouldn't need runas in this instance.

Comment: No, parent company pushes uac off via gpo.

Comment: Oof. Then you'll have to jump through all kinds of hoops for plenty of other things as well.